# Qual é a forma correta: "todo pai e mãe deveria" ou "todo pai e mãe deveriam"?

Tags: gramática, concordância-verbal, concordância

Qual é a forma correta dentre as duas abaixo?
As duas formas podem ser consideradas corretas?
Qual é a regra gramatical que se aplica?

1. *"... que todo pai e mãe deveria"*
2. *"... que todo pai e mãe deveriam"*

Comment: "podem ser consideradas", diria eu.

Answer (score 2):

Todo pai e mãe deveria. 'Todo' evoca o sentido de conjunto, portanto exige singular. *Mas é "pai e mãe".* Sim, mas o "todo" agrupa tanto os pais quanto as mães em um mesmo conjunto.

Todavia, se fosse "todo pai e toda mãe", o correto seria "deveriam", pois são dois conjuntos, o conjunto de todos os pais e o conjunto de todas as mães.

Answer (score 1):

todo pai e [toda] mãe seria plural. Todo pai e mãe deveriam etc.

O sujeito da frase contém dois substantivos na posição de sujeito.

A explicação se encontra aqui:

"Neste caso se trata de **sujeito composto**, com dois núcleos ligados por E, portanto o verbo deve fazer a concordância no plural:

Todo pai e (toda) mãe têm direito a saber o que está acontecendo.
(= Todos os pais e mães têm )"

[sujeito composto](http://www.linguabrasil.com.br/nao-tropece-detail.php?id=846)